# Celery is not auto-discovering shared tasks in other modules

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I am trying to use celery w/ Django and not getting very far.  I am also using django-celery-beat.  I don't seem to be discovering the shared tasks in other modules.

Here is some code:

**proj/proj/settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  "django_celery_beat",
  "proj",
  "proj.myapp",
]
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://user:password@localhost:5672/vhost"
```

**proj/proj/__init__.py:**

```
from proj.celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

**proj/proj/celery.py:**

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

if not settings.configured:
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

**proj/app/tasks.py:**

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

When I look at the admin interface for django-beat I only see the "proj.celery.debug_task" and not "myapp.tasks.add"

Any ideas why?

---

**edit:**

*Argh!!*  It turns out that the "faker" library (which I was using in my silly test tasks) hadn't been installed in my environment.  However, celery's `autodiscover_tasks` function fails silently - so I didn't know what the error was.

So basically, it was programmer stupidity.

Comment: your app is registered in settings as myapp and shown in the file path as app (proj/app/tasks.py), is one a typo?

Comment: @grrrrrr - does the app name have to mirror the file path?

Comment: When you use `manage.py startapp appname` it creates them that way. not sure how django would match them up otherwise https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/#creating-the-polls-app

Comment: Here are the docs for INSTALLED_APPS -- bottom line needs to be dotted path https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @grrrrrr - Thanks for that.  I have updated INSTALLED_APPS.  However, beat still fails to discover shared_tasks.

Comment: if the file structure is proj/app/tasks.py then the INSTALLED_APPS should have 'app' as an entry

Comment: there has to be a way to force autodiscover_tasks to not fail silently, that seems like an asinine design choice